# SQL Server time difference

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Simple question, not so simple answer!  If I have two dates in format arrival time, departure time respectively,

```
2014-10-16 10:29:42.000, 2014-10-16 12:04:48.000
```

how do I get the time difference between the two i.e. 'Loading Time' in hours and minutes?  hh:mm?

Thanks!

Comment: To get it in seconds you can do `select datediff(second, start_time, end_time) as loading_time
from your_table`

Comment: i know how to use datediff to get seconds or minutes between two times I don't know how to display the difference in format hh:mm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give you 95 mins in your case...

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi,'2014-10-16 10:29:42.000', '2014-10-16 12:04:48.000')
```

To convert it, you could use...

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(minute,
                                    DATEDIFF(mi, '2014-10-16 10:29:42.000',
                                             '2014-10-16 12:04:48.000'), 0), 114)
```

Comment: This is great, simple and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Since the difference might be more then 24 hours you will need to display days in case off.

```
Declare @a Datetime
Declare @b Datetime
Set @b = '20141016 12:04:48.000'
Set @a= '20141016 10:29:42.000'
Select Isnull(Cast(NULLIF(DateDiff(dd,@a,@b),0) as Varchar(10)) + ' d ','') 
      + Convert (Varchar(20),Case when @a>@b then @a-@b else @b-@a end ,108)
```

> > 01:35:06

```
Set @b = '20141018 12:04:48.000'
Set @a= '20141016 10:29:42.000'
Select Isnull(Cast(NULLIF(DateDiff(dd,@a,@b),0) as Varchar(10)) + ' d ','') 
     + Convert (Varchar(20),Case when @a>@b then @a-@b else @b-@a end ,108)
```

> > 2 d 01:35:06

Comment: If I could mark this as an answer as well I would, however I believe the more simple function below will serve my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

First get the total seconds and divide it 3600 to get the hours.
Then take the reminder and divide it by 60 to get the minutes.
Convert those two integer values to `VARCHAR` as concatenate it.

### Query

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), FLOOR(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2014-10-16 10:29:42.000',
                                        '2014-10-16 12:04:48.000') / 3600))
    + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ( FLOOR(DATEDIFF(SECOND,
                                                  '2014-10-16 10:29:42.000',
                                                  '2014-10-16 12:04:48.000')
                                         % 3600) ) / 60)
```

### [Find demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31bab/1)